# Is it possible to be more accurate than a second for the snipping function below? (MATLAB, ffmpeg)

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg, command-line

```
snip = 'ffmpeg -i %s -ss %d:%d:%d -t %d:%d:%d -async 1 -strict -2 %s';
snipstr = sprintf(snip,UncutFile,StartHRS,StartMIN,StartSEC,DurHRS,DurMIN,DurSEC,CutFile);
runsnip = system(snipstr);
```

These lines snip a video based on starting time inputs and duration inputs. I need my videos to be snipped to times more accurate than a second.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [time duration](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) says:

> There are two accepted syntaxes for expressing time duration.
>
> ```
> [-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]
> ```
>
> `HH` expresses the number of hours, `MM` the number of minutes for a
> maximum of 2 digits, and `SS` the number of seconds for a maximum of 2
> digits. The `m` at the end expresses decimal value for `SS`.
>
> or
>
> ```
> [-]S+[.m...][s|ms|us]
> ```
>
> `S` expresses the number of seconds, with the optional decimal part `m`.
> The optional literal suffixes `s`, `ms` or `us` indicate to interpret
> the value as seconds, milliseconds or microseconds, respectively.
>
> In both expressions, the optional `-` indicates negative duration.

Example: `-ss 01:23:45.4` or `-ss 5025.4`